# A problem in Straight Lines chapter

Tags: geometry

If the sum of the reciprocals of the intercepts made by a variable straight line on the axes of coordinates is a constant, then probe that the line always passes through a fixed point.

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let the line be x/a + y/b = 1 where a and b are intercepts made by the line on the co-ordinate axes. (1)

It is given to  us that 1/a + 1/b = c = constant.

Hence 1/ac + 1/bc = 1  (2)

We see, (1/c)/a + (1/c)/b = 1

Hence the line passes through a fixed point (1/c,1/c)